# Jolly gerrymandering

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, grid, printable-ascii

### Background

The United States has a unique love of gerrymandering––the deliberate manipulation of an electoral district to predict certain voting results. Just recently there was a [gerrymandering case](https://www.politico.com/story/2017/10/03/supreme-court-gerrymandering-wisconsin-arguments-243401) brought before the Supreme Court. Gerrymandering, especially when related to race, is ruled illegal and results in the requirement to redraw the district lines.

Given a rectangular map of a municipality (2d array), you will draw district lines to help your party get the most representation. That is, you will gerrymander. Every municipality has two parties, `0` and `1`. The map will be comprised of squares with either `0` or `1` on them. Here is an example map:

[image]

### Challenge

You will group the map into districts so that the `1` party will get at least the number of districts specified by the Input.

### Input

The input will consist of a map, the number of districts to draw, and the minimum number of districts the `1` party needs to win (the minimum score).

### Output

The output will be a map of the districts. Each district will be uniquely comprised of a capitalized letter of the alphabet. Yes, this means that there will not be more than 26 districts.

If there is no possible output where the inputted party wins enough districts, either:

1. Print “We tried...”
2. Fatally error because the party was irreparably injured by the  election results
3. Or both

### Rules (also very important)

1. All districts must be contiguous
2. Districts may not have other districts in them
3. Each district must have at least four nodes in it. The input will be consistent with the rules, meaning that there will be at least `number_of_districts * 4` nodes in the map
4. The score of each party is the number of districts it has a majority in
5. If a district has the same number of `0`s and `1`s, then neither party benefits from it
6. Normal no-cheating rules
7. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
1. Input       1. Output       2. Input       2. Output     3. Input      3. Output
districts: 5   Image and map   districts: 3   Image below   districts: 3  fatal error
min wins: 3                    min wins: 3                  min wins: 3
map:                           map:                         map:
00000110000    AAAAAAAAAAA     101101                       101101
10000010000    AAAAAAAAAAA     100000                       100000
10010000011    AAAAAAAAAAA     011011                       011011
11001110000    BBBBBBBAAAA     111111                       100111
00111111000    BBBBBBBAAAA     
01111111000    CCCCCDDDAAA     
01111111001    CCCCCDDDAAA     
01000111100    EEEEEDDDDDD     
00000001000    EEEEEDDDDDD
```

[image][image]

Of course, your program should work for *any* valid test case, not just these ones.

Comment: @Arnauld, yes they are only illustrative. The real output should be like in the first test case with the letters of the alphabet. I changed the tag to reflect this.

Comment: A simple partition of the first test case would be something [like this](https://pasteboard.co/GVX78Gx.png). Is that correct?

Comment: @Arnauld, yes, that's valid.

Comment: So for the 3rd example, if we divided it into horizontal rows, each 1 district tall, then the 1s would win 3 to 1 yes?

Comment: @MichaelDorgan, yes, except that you may only have three districts in that one.

Comment: Ah - hence the fail.  Missed the district count.  Thanks

Comment: This reminds me a whole lot of what had to be done for char based graphics on Nintendo handhelds from DMG up to DS.  You were given specific shapes to cut graphics into and had to minimize the number of shapes used as you could only have a hardware defined number of sprites (shapes) in use.  That was not an easy problem.

Comment: I think this problem may be more suitable for fastest-code?

Comment: interesting, tough problem.  is there an efficient algorithm for this?  what is its complexity?

Comment: "districts must not have other districts within them" means that something like `AAA
ABA
AAA` wouldn't be allowed, right?

Comment: @Giuseppe, exactly

Comment: What is the format of the 'map'? String with newlines? Sequence of strings? 2D Array of booleans?

Comment: @Ourous, any of those works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>938</s> <s>896</s>  <s>858</s> 952 bytes

```r
function(N,M,m){U="We tried...
"
L=length
A=matrix
W=which
K=sum
S=sample
G=unique
H=function(s,p=s-1){Y=S(c(s-j,s+j,p*(p%%j>0),(s+1)*(s%%j>0)))
Y[Y>0&Y<=k]}
C=function(v,z=W(r==v))K(z%%j<2,z-j<0,(z+j)>k)
m=A(strsplit(m,"")[[1]],1)
i=W(m<0)[1]-1
m=((t(A(m,i+1))[,1:i]>0)-.5)*2
if((K(m)<M&(N-M)<1)|K(m>0)<(3*M))cat(U) else{j=max(1,nrow(m))
k=i*j;w=g=T
while(w<9&g){Z=R=N;Q=M;b=0
r=A(0,j,i)
while(b<9&g){s=W(r<1)
s=s[S(L(s))][1:min(L(s),R)]
r[s]=1:L(s);a=0
while(K(r<1)>0&a<(k^2)){a=a+1
s=S(W(r>0&r<=R),1);p=r[s]
Y=H(s)
Y=Y[r[Y]<1]
if(L(Y)){Y=Y[order(m[Y])]
if(K(m[r==p]>1))r[Y[1]]=p else r[Y[L(Y)]]=p}}
if(a<(k^2)){for(v in 1:R){if(K(m[r==v])>0){r[r==v]=max(k,max(r))+1
Q=Q-1;Z=Z-1}}
if(Q<1){g=F
for(v in 1:R)r[r==v]=max(k,max(r))+1
for(v in G(c(r)))g=g|(K(r==v)<4)|(L(G(r[H(W(r==v))]))+C(v))<3}}
b=b+1;r[r<=R]=0;R=Z}
w=w+1}
if(g)cat(U) else{u=G(c(r))
for(v in 1:L(u))r[r==u[v]]=v
cat(paste(apply(A(LETTERS[r],j,i),1,paste,collapse=""),collapse="
"))}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPbbtpAEH3fr7CQEs3AgrykfSh4kKKIJhIXCUgUGcuVDHGIAYPr5ZJC@HY6axOSVCoP9pydM2dmj4f02KUryxIdqlr8ii0SBdv8lDJPoXLwHp@gEiatTpwsyoE4hf/ESmSVORC2fRYVBSGadHxeL8araLmAruzIGPcPVHgMrVUahU@VSoVJbZqHi8nqRVxTHPD5q3ik7Us0fhEt0utYDEgHcTIPxS2tF9HvdSju6CyqZUK6rHDv0gDGoMtTqUtTmRQhubiYNmyUoEsKi6BziChcz23Yl65DM/8gbj6kNnJHj5ASbRBbsGO@U5W78tSxJexKU2zMUMR0DXqV6mQerSCWhQJ6nvJ9qVBEXBw7NjIuKyYCrOCaORG3R0@qWuRz/3LlOxarInoGaEGMTucSuuUOOgrfGDPBgatiB3EcrOABrXCuw/2UfXkFJRfpcss1KGYUFaf1LU3oXrBT8xC2zo/LCe6H1KduvUed@ohskfKwtpzKCE@sUc7S5prcUWjS3gDaoBF9T9XiaJEB2UdfpJ72SdUMrgcsliu0skK2L3Bg9quKuA8oKClWGgCLciJ1qI/sRz0hIyFcumMJfrle6rm@o3xz@Ta4aL6Z6y3TpzCFmFOYZdgFj79B4jfYNq4w9lKSGWEZaCrNyeFg2OcxnpcpbKxoYalaH/cfOhufp8V9mseZkTNpnikiz92jXlnVhzQsq1ywx9fbT@in@CL4v/Iz6ZZ3j49wQpM3Y5JZIucbvvFFbyH17uB9sXyuuwEOnCtuOKJRSdVZnU3zya73aXgQW9qWVDbM5MsarOnU5fNsbVhjPt7a27AvG2FKkkCvQgiSZP6Hd7DdvL9v9gde6mfLIJXM8nK8nM@DRIfEa/wJiALi4XA4Nk//2ONf)

A massive <s>>900</s> <s>>800</s> (nope!) >900 bytes solution.
The code works as follows. Let N be the number of electoral districts and M the minimum number of district where 1 wishes to have a majority.

First, the code randomly assigns N districts to different groups. Next, it randomly expands them, i.e. adds a district to a randomly selected group, ensuring that the district is next to a district already belonging to that group. In the expansion process, it gives precedence to a district with a 1 majority, if the district group is not yet a full 1 majority; if the group is already a certain 1 majority, then it gives precedence to a 0 district. It continues until all districts have been assigned.

Every group where there is a majority for the 1 party is stored, and its districts are locked. If there are at least M groups with a majority of 1, then everything is good and <s>we can print the result</s> we can check whether there are at least 4 districts in each group. If the cutoff of 4 districts is met, then we can happily print the result. Otherwise, the code tries to reassign the districts that are not locked to as many groups as available, i.e. N - #stored-groups.

The codes tries a few times (9 times). If it fails, it resets everything and starts again. It does so for other 9 times before giving up and printing "we tried...".

If the code does not succeed at first, try again a few times. I tuned the number of repetitions such that it can run in TIO under a minute. However if there is a solution, this code can (eventually) find it. The randomness part of the algorithm gives a non-zero probability that, if there is a solution, it can find it. The limited number of trials is the only limiting factor to success.

EDIT: added the control that no district group can be fully surrounded by just another one, unless the district group has districts on the edge of the given square. I think I missed it at first.

Comment: Can you remove any newlines?

Comment: I did. I also assigned longer function names to single letters, and replaced a few `==0` with `<1` when the variable was strictly integer and positive.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff here that can be trivially golfed but this is a good first attempt at an answer, so +1, and I'll be suggesting edits I a couple hours once I'm not on my phone!

Comment: [858 bytes](https://goo.gl/eZ7P6C) -- "regular" golfs, cleaning up the use of braces with `if...else` statements, swapping `c` for `as.vector`, changing `"\n"` with literal newlines, and using the fact that `>` will automatically coerce numbers to characters silently and compare their codepoints. There's probably some other golfs I did that I can't remember but this is a start. I think there are a few more things we can tweak down but I'm not 100% sure I understand the code...

Comment: Nice one! I took inspiration. By comparing to your code I also found a bug in mine that would sometimes lead to very small district groups (less than 4 districts). It is now fixed.

Comment: Would this program usually work but not necessarily always because of the randomness and trying only at most 81 times?

Comment: Yes, the number of trials could be increased at the cost of some bytes but then it may time out on tio. --edit: I think I missed checking that a group is not fully surrounded by another group. I'll add that shortly. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 1067 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
R=range
def P(b):
 c=[(x,y)for x,r in E(b)for y,_ in E(r)]
 while c:
  C=c.pop(0)
  q,s=[C],[C]
  while q:
   x,y=q.pop(0)
   for X,Y in[(0,1),(0,-1),(-1,0),(1,0)]:
    T=(x+X,y+Y)
    if T in c and T not in s and b[x+X][y+Y]==b[x][y]:q+=[T];s+=[T]
  yield s;c=[*{*c}-{*s}]
def S(b,g):
 k=[0,0]
 for x,y in g:k[b[x][y]]+=1
 return k[1]>k[0]
def F(n,m,b):
 B=eval(str(b))
 for G in P(B):
  if len(G)<4:
   for x,y in G:B[x][y]=int(not B[x][y])
 q=[(B,L:=[*P(B)],sum(S(b,i)for i in L))]
 H=[L]
 while 1:
  B,G,C=q.pop(0)
  O=max(j for k in B for j in k)+1
  if len(G)==n and sum(S(b,i)for i in G)>=m:
   for Y,i in E(G,65):
    for x,y in i:B[x][y]=chr(Y)
   return B
  for x in R(len(b)+1):
   for y in R(len(b[0])+1):
    for X in R(x+1,len(b)+1):
     for Y in R(y+1,len(b[0])+1):
      if(X-x)*(Y-y)>=4 and S(b,T:=[(j,k)for j in R(x,X)for k in R(y,Y)]):
       Q=eval(str(B))
       for U,I in T:Q[U][I]=O
       if len(W:=[*P(Q)])<=n and len(W)>=len(G)and W not in H and all(len(i)>=4 for i in W)and(N_C:=sum(S(b,i)for i in W))>=C:q+=[(Q,W,N_C)];H+=[W]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVNRT@JAEH6@/oqNL@zCYrqil0t1fShRNCEqHgZIb2MKFC2UFtp6R2P87dzMbql4MXcP16TtTOebb2a@6a6K/DmJW99W6XZ7IYP4ZRmkfh5Y9zL146fAmgYzckfHzLHIRHp0wws2S1Ky4SkJY3IBEXQL/mjclCmL/HoOo4BMIIW05eRwlayozcBZ80x6bcXhBs@g1ogCukKu34EEOYd8BJwetblgHJ5NfDUFt@GFT6UzSV/STWPIi8ZIZ5JwRvrYy4T48RTMOMnRzbQ79gCrPAArKcEBUznrhvT66jTTL@AowiCakuwU5q2/1idvzdd69qa0Et/pmD@hFgvp2dwGtBGjwBJPzsIrOVVDCoukQf6SxmThCXW@8GxDcUljvuRaUFcGP/2IZnkKMjLD1UGmO@piHGeJgph22Nmxs5OlLNZxXFNKhnFOccjSB541LMrlXQf6RybFs5clxdZDvawQ87sMN3UlvW61MIE1XN7h7f1d3Mqlv6FzXXuBma4252guWEPstyllrGX@pF6HnctlNcSIh@Z/6fCvJ8wscm@4sBpu8pxSs9hSTNcqkYi7p1h3DF2wirrYC4DmVcz8Uya4aQj@MbNsy4SLXfhDPs5Jh80Nq9NRs4BxjvWsOGcfpKZzvmCVMlCDD1mlGXDyEVMVE@m9r95lbPcV8Q/8GjP6Ts97UN61kre7aCnzwOy1B3Rnpd76M3RktoBfBrv//koD/CjSioS67WopA8TSm8e2Iz9Z2YABuq2PB@3xAQccU6dX4A7UNhNEkoODA8vGSwh8WsI4O7t0hYVhUWK0ZRyrNP@whaUzjWP4DZeF9bKjsrDAqqKsaWkHK@FlgK2/AnUBDcRTmSeP48RPpzSDHX0p/zXPqy/9FYUDBrKoSpdZGOVBSm@SOOAkO8xWUZjT2o@4hkfKslYpnkj0D@dJGFOkqBmbX9IT3uLvxQTDa5fSrNVPbPYPgtYHgqP/JWhpgu1v)

### Notes:

1. A little longer than the other solution, but deterministic and runs in ~3.65 seconds
2. Fatally-errors if there is no possible output